# I need help finding the PSF and characterizations of the following

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals

My professor explained this to me in a super convoluted way, so hopefully someone can explain this to me better.

I'm trying to find the PSF of the following signals. I also need to check if it's FIR or IIR and comment on BIBO-ness.

a) $y(m,n) = 3x(m,n) + 9$

and

b) $y(m,n) = \sum_{k = -inf}^{m} \sum_{l = -inf}^{n}x(k,l)$

I believe the PSF of a signal is just the output from the delta function as the input.

So the PSF for the two signals should just be $h(m,n) = 3\delta(m,n) + 9$ and $h(m,n) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{m} \sum_{l = -\infty}^{n}\delta(m,n) = \infty$

I think both signals are IIR because both of them have a h(m,n) response that is of non-zero infinite length? Is this correct?